# How can I put a sign for "angle alpha 40°" into a Graphics[Triangle ..]] like in Mathworld "Triangle"?

Tags: graphics, drawing

How can one place the description/symbol "Alpha 40°" into the corner of a triangle drawn by Graphics/Triangle as it can be seen in the texts and drawings of Mathworld for example like one can see if he is looking for "Triangle"? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Since you can input Unicode characters in Mathematica (e.g. `FromCharacterCode[8736]` for you case), your question is how to place text in a given position. You can look up the hep for `Epilog`.

Comment: `Graphics[{Line[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], 
  Text[Style[
    FromCharacterCode[8736] <> "45" <> FromCharacterCode[176], 
    FontColor -> Blue, FontSize -> 18], {.90, 0.03}]}]`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer (from the comment by [Hector Aug 21 '16 at 19:45](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124487/how-can-i-put-a-sign-for-angle-alpha-40-into-a-graphicstriangle-like-in#comment336885_124487)):

```
Graphics[{Line[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], 
  Text[Style[
    FromCharacterCode[8736] <> "45" <> FromCharacterCode[176], 
    FontColor -> Blue, FontSize -> 18], {.90, 0.03}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, it's CW and an upvote will take it off the unanswered list.